# How mapping Geography column SQL Server 2012 + fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, geolocation, fluent-nhibernate

For storing the location in formation in the server I tried to create one table which contains the Geography column in SQL Server 2012.

I am using Fluent NHibernate ORM in the application. In my business object I have a property for location column.

[DataMember]
public virtual DbGeography Location { get; set; }

Map(x => x.Location) ???

How do I map DbGeography type property to the Geography column in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate does not support spatial datatypes out of the box. Have a look at [NHibernate.Spatial](http://nhforge.org/wikis/spatial/introduction.aspx)
I use it in a project and it works well.

Comment: I did in sql 2008 and worked perfectly, but unable to do in sql 2012 know if it really works with the SQL 2012?